# Utilizing Samba Shares Without using Winbind

Tags: rhel, samba, kerberos, smb, sssd

I am curious if it is possible to use samba shares without using winbind. In our current environment we are using SSSD, Kerberos, and Samba to complete the required tasks such as joining the windows domain and setting up active directory. Since we are using SSSD instead of winbind how can we setup a samba share for the Windows machines to access using the current implementation? I can share some of the configuration as necessary.

Using RedHat Enterprise 6 and Samba v 3.6.9

Answer (score 0):

With RHEL/CentOS 7 and Samba4, you can simply join the AD domain with `realmd`/`sssd`, configure Samba to serve shares the standar way (`security=ads`), and then it should simply work. The only catch here is that joining the domain using SSSD doesn't seem to set the domain SID for Samba (`net getdomainsid` reports "Could not fetch domain SID"), and thus Samba fails to authenticate domain users.

You can then set the domain SID manually with `net setdomainsid`.

Comment: I don't see that problem at all. I've got several fileservers running SAMBA 4 with SSSD as the authentication layer to AD, and no Winbind in sight. Mind you, I'm on Debian rather than RHEL.

Comment: Does your `net getdomainsid` command correctly show your AD domain SID? If so, I'm very interested in knowing how does `samba` get that ID without `winbind`...

Comment: `sudo net getdomainsid` returns me the local machine SID and the domain SID. (I can't run it as an ordinary user because `/var/lib/samba/private/secrets.tdb` is quite reasonably unreadable.)