# Samba file server + AD + SSSD without Winbind

Tags: samba, active-directory, sssd

Currently have a CentOS8 server AD integrated using SSSD + automatic SID->UID mapping/generation. I would like to setup some file shares to make use of AD groups, but am struggling to get it set up. Does anybody have an example config that does not make use of winbind? Currently have the following:

```
[global]
   workgroup = <domain netbios name>

   security = ads
   realm = <domain fqdn>
   domain master = no
   local master = no
   preferred master = no

   client min protocol = SMB3

   vfs objects = acl_xattr
   map acl inherit = yes

   log level = 5

   idmap config * : backend =  sss
   idmap config * : range = 10001-2000100000

   kerberos method = secrets and keytab
```

I'm not familiar with setting up Samba, so maybe some of those settings dont make sense/are superfluous? I get the following error when trying to start Samba:

```
[2021/02/08 19:26:53.511544,  3] ../../source3/auth/token_util.c:788(finalize_local_nt_token)
Failed to check for local Guests membership (NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_MIX)
[2021/02/08 19:26:53.511550,  0] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1403(make_new_session_info_guest)
create_local_token failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_MIX
[2021/02/08 19:26:53.511603,  0] ../../source3/smbd/server.c:2052(main)
ERROR: failed to setup guest info.
```

Thank you

Comment: From my experience the success rate for SSSD/Samba combination depends vastly on the precise versions. Some versions of Samba talk directly to SSSD. Some require winbind as a shim. Yet still others don't work. If you can replace SSSD with winbind I'd say you've a better chance.

Comment: I will go further, you MUST replace sssd with winbind if you want shares. From Samba 4.8.0 smbd must go through winbind to get to AD. If you just want authentication, then sssd can be used, just not with Samba.

Comment: @RowlandPenny thats disappointing that Winbind must be used - my understanding was that SSSD is the preferred tool of choice for Linux/AD interaction.

Comment: @roaima I noticed you had mentioned in a comment a couple of years ago that you use a Samba/SSSD/sans Winbind setup. Would you be willing to share versions/config at all? Thanks https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168773/utilizing-samba-shares-without-using-winbind

Comment: I've reverted all my servers to Samba+winbind, with no sssd. This was the only way I could get reliable operation through upgrades, and they've been stable for several months now. I hate to say it but sssd does nothing useful for me at all on servers running Samba

Comment: The problem is that sssd uses code from the winbind libs, which was okay until Samba 4.8.0 was released. Before 4.8.0, smbd could talk directly to AD, from 4.8.0, smbd must go via winbind to AD, because virtually the same code is in sssd and winbind, you cannot use them both on the same computer. Once I understood how to configure smb.conf, I found that there was very little that sssd could do that winbind couldn't and what it couldn't wasn't really worth doing.

Comment: @Rowland it's good to hear I'm not alone!

Answer (score 0):

I have a small working Samba setup without winbind that uses SSSD/Kerberos for authentication and and controls access to shares by Windows AD group. I got the setup from here originally: http://www.hexblot.com/blog/centos-7-active-directory-and-samba. I am no Samba expert so I can't offer a lot of explanation but hopefully this points you in the direction you are looking. The server is currently running Debian 10.8, Samba 4.9.5, and SSSD 1.16.3

Here is the global section of smb.conf and one share:

```
[global]
workgroup = <domain netbios name>
security = ads
encrypt passwords = yes
passdb backend = tdbsam
realm = <kerberos realm (normally domain FQDN in all caps)>
map to guest = Bad User
kerberos method = secrets and keytab

# Not interested in printers
load printers = no
cups options = raw

# This stops an annoying message from appearing in logs
printcap name = /dev/null

[backups]
comment = My shared folder
path = /srv/smbshares/backups
public = no
writable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = @"it@domain.fqdn"
create mask = 660
directory mask = 770
```

That is all I can say for sure but I will offer a little speculation since I do not have the time to experiment:
One big difference I notice between my config and yours is that you use idmap and I do not. Since the error mentions a problem with local group membership, that is where I suspect the problem is. Have you tried specifying tdb as the default (*) domain backend and then sss as a domain-specific one (something like this - see https://www.mankier.com/8/idmap_sss):

```
idmap config <AD-DOMAIN-SHORTNAME> : backend        = sss
idmap config <AD-DOMAIN-SHORTNAME> : range          = 200000-2147483647
idmap config * : backend        = tdb
idmap config * : range          = 100000-199999
```

Comment: The gotcha happens at password renewal time, if it's going to happen at all. That's around 30 days from first set-up. If you've been running longer than that then you've got a working configuration